# Z80 assembly push and pop a value

Tags: z80

How I can use a value that has been stored into a register after N lines of code? For example I want to use the value that has been stored into `bc` later in `INIT`. I tried with push and pop but after the `cp 2` instruction the program won't jump to INIT2.

```
    ld bc, 2
    push bc

...

INIT:
     pop bc
     cp 2
     jp z, INIT2
```

Comment: It might help to read [mcve].  You don't show the rest of your code, so I have to guess that you did something else in between that changed the stack, like pushing another value or popping the value into another register.

Comment: I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve,but it might help to know that `cp ` only works with the 8-bit `A` register. If you are trying to compare `BC` to 2, you'll need to check that `B` (the upper 8 bits of BC) is 0 and `C` (the lower 8 bits of BC) is 2. There are clever tricks to do this, but the easy way (if you aren't used to Z80) is a crude, `ld a,b \ cp 0 \ jr nz,ne2 \ ld a,c \ cp 2 \ jr z,INIT2`.

Answer (score 1):

Values can be stored in three places:

1. a register
2. a memory address
3. a port

When using the stack you are simply putting the value of a register pair in (`push`), or loading the value of a register pair from (`pop`), an address in memory pointed to by the stack pointer (`sp`). Since the stack is just memory, the meaning of any value is arbitray, you will need to balance your `pop` and `push` to pop the value you intended - only you know what is actually on the stack.

An easier and less error prone approach - albeit slower - is to dedicate some memory to storing your value:

```
var.counter: defw 0

...

    ld bc,2
    ld (var.counter),bc

...

INIT:
     ld bc,(var.counter)
     cp 2
     jp z, INIT2
```

Sometimes (if you are executing in RAM) limited self modifying code can be effective:

```
    ld bc,2
    ld (smc.counter+1),bc

...

INIT:
smc.counter:
     ld bc,0
     cp 2
     jp z, INIT2
```

And as mentioned in the comments to your question `cp` compares the value with the accumulator (register `a`) and not register pair `bc`.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it right: `CP` compares the A register, so you'd need to get your value back into the `A` register:

```
LD   B, 2
PUSH BC
...
POP  AF
CP   2
JP   Z, INIT2
```

Since PUSH and POP work on register pairs only, you have no option of pushing/popping a single byte. Instead, we push BC, with C value being whatever it happens to be. Then when we pop AF, the flags get set to some random value that C had, but it doesn't matter since CP overwrites them anyway.

If you wanted to store a 16-bit value, and then do a 16-bit comparison, you would do it as follows:

```
LD   BC, 1234
PUSH BC
...
POP  BC
SCF
LD   HL, 1234-1 ; value to compare with - 1
SBC  HL, BC     ; Z is set when BC was equal to 1234
JP   Z, INIT2
```